# Get FileInfo On Itself?

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo

My C# program is in the form of a single .exe file. Therfore, the user can store it anywhere and name it anything. How can I use the FileInfo class to get its Attributes if I don't know the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: This would return path to the DLL if placed in one of the APP's class libraries, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx): `Gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing`

Comment: He specified that his program is in the form of a single .exe file, so it will return the URI string of that .exe file, but i agree - your solution is more general and therefore better

Comment: +1 You're right, I've overlooked sorry for that. In this case I would say your solution is better because more lightweight +If I run application from VS debugger my solution will return `app.vshost.exe` and your more correct -`app.exe`

Comment: Niko, @sll : It's respectful discussion like that makes SE the best community on the web. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var info = new FileInfo(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

PS: this will return you a path to an executable even this code snipped has been calles in one of the solution's project (DLL) but please be aware that in case of run within the VS debugger it returns `ApplicationExeName.vshost.exe` so in this case you might found more useful solution of *Niko Drašković* (`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the working directory using

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

More at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)

and the file name using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

I think!